# Do delegated elements for an event need to be present when binding In JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am encountering condition where part of the page isn't present when I try to bind elements on that part of the page. I would like to know if I can avoid the issue by delegating off of a container that is present. To give an example, suppose that I have the following:

```
$('.contianer').on('click', '.button1', function () {
  console.log('success');
});
```

Suppose that the code above get's triggered before '.button1' exists but '.container' does exist. Will the console log success in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why delegation is so sexy

Comment: Have you tried it out?

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Maybe because of the typo (container vs contianer)? If you need help getting it to work, please share the whole code you used.